# ZSH completion depending on the provided argument

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Is there a way to access already provided argument as a variable in a ZSH completion scripts?

here is the example:

```
#compdef test

_test_comp(){
 t=($(cat /tmp/file_with_opts))
 _wanted t expl "availavle options" compadd -a t
}

_arguments -C -S  \
 '-f[input file]:filename:_files' \
 '*:test_autocomplete:_test_comp'
```

the `test` script will pick up options from the hardcoded file `/tmp/file_with_opts`, I'd like to be able to pick up autocomplete options from a file defined via `-f`. Or rather if `-f <filename>` is defined I'd like to parse this file and not the default one. Any hint how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems something like an XY problem; what exactly motivates this changing of the completion via a provided option? Like could the change instead be done via an environment variable, or why does the completion need to vary?

Anyways, a file at some point during the option processing may cause problems depending on where `-f ...` appears relative to other things on the command line. Also the completion code will be repeatedly invoked so maintaining state across different calls to the same and new instances of a command may be tricky. And also `$(cat /tmp/file_with_opts)` is bad as it needlessly forks out to `cat` and then splits the contents on...well, who knows.

With these problems in mind, one way to figure out what options are available is to add something like `set > ~/tmp/what-is-set` to an appropriate part of the completion code, then hit tab with the cursor at various places with and without the `-f ...` option and then check the output file to see what things are available to a completion script:

```
% grep file_ what-is-set
BUFFER='foo  -f file_with_opts '
RBUFFER=' -f file_with_opts '
opt_args=( [-f]=file_with_opts )
words=( foo '' -f file_with_opts )
```

In that case I was tab completing just after `foo` and before `-f ...`, so to vary the completion behavior one could check `BUFFER` or better yet the `words` array as `BUFFER` might have `-f ...` from other commands unrelated to your program that could confuse your completion script.

So if we loop over `words`, we can vary what file is read depending on whether (without much error checking) the `-f ...` option is present with something like:

```
#compdef foo

local curcontext="$curcontext" state line ret=1

_arguments -C -S  \
  '-f[input file]:filename:_files' \
  '*:options:->vary' \
  && ret=0

case "$state" in
  vary)
    integer i
    local optsfile
    #set > ~/tmp/what-is-set
    # default filename
    optsfile=~/tmp/file_with_opts
    for (( i = 1; i <= $#words - 1; i++ )); do
      if [[ $words[$i] == -f ]]; then
        optsfile=$words[$((i+1))]
        break
      fi
    done
    # cat-free read of file with split on newlines
    t=(${(f)"$(<$optsfile)"})
    _wanted t expl "available options" compadd -a t
  ;;
esac

return $ret
```

It may be helpful to study the existing completions under the `$fpath[-1]` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much! this clarifies a lot for me. I can't use environment vars in this case. It is very handy to pick up completions from a file, but sometimes the program operates on a different file and thus it would be silly to provide wrong completions. Thank you also for providing example for cat-free read of file it is definitely useful and finally I know what it means in other _completions files on my system:).